# JPA @ManyToOne get row even if foreign attribute does not reference to any foreign row

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have this `Customer` attribute on `Sale` class :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Customer customer;
```

The problem is if `customer_id` does not refer to any Customer (after deleting it for example), the sale row is not returned. It seems that Customer attribute blocks the sale row retrieving if it does not refer to any customer in `Customer` table.

How to get the sale row even if `customer_id` does not refer to any Customer.

Comment: are you asking to get Sales of Customer OR all Sales records?

Comment: @Mrcode. I want to get all sales records, even if the sales don't have a (valid) customer (id).

Comment: then execute SQL against db as "select * from Sale";

Comment: @Mrcode. There is surely a way to solve this problem using JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: Sales table has lost relation with Customer then how will you get Sales based on Customer?

Comment: Can you post your criteria/hql/ query? You should be able to get all salles, when asked directly, missing relation with Customer should not be problem.

Comment: List<Sale> allSalesInTable = session.createQuery("FROM Sale").getResultList();

Comment: @Tijkijiki Please see my posted answer.

Comment: @Mrcode. Please see my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem :
I'm getting the `Sale` records like following :

```
@Query("SELECT s from Sale s where cast(s.id as string) like :x or s.invoiceNumber like :x or s.customer.name like :x or s.paymentMethod like :x or s.note like :x or s.invoiceNumber like :x")
    public Page<Sale> search(@Param("x") String keyword, Pageable pageable);
```

The problem is that in the query there is `s.customer.name like :x`, but I should add a `LEFT JOIN s.customer` to the query.
Here is the correct final HQL :
`SELECT s from Sale s left join s.customer where cast(s.id as string) like :x or s.invoiceNumber like :x or s.customer.name like :x or s.paymentMethod like :x or s.note like :x or s.invoiceNumber like :x`